# Взаимодействие между процессами одного windows-пользователя

Tags: .net, pipes, ipc, inter-process

Необходмо, чтобы в рамках windows-сесси одного пользователя одно приложение могло отправлять текстовые данные другому приложению.

Попытался использовать именованные pipes. Сервер слушает ассинхроно, клинеты посылют сообщения. Все хорошо до того момента, когда на этой же машине другой  windows-пользователь пытается запустить сервер.

Может быть нужно именовать pipes таким образом, что бы имя получалась уникальным для каждого ползователя? Какие уникальные идентификаторы я для этого могу использовать?

Или может быть нужо использовать для коммункации что-то другое?

Что бы было понятно, что я использую_ привожу код клиента, который посылает сообщения:

```
    public void Send(string SendStr, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous)) {

            // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
            // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);

            if (pipeStream.IsConnected) {

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream)) {
                    sw.WriteLine(SendStr);
                }

            } else
                throw new ApplicationException("Can not establish the messaging.");
        }
    }
```

Ну и сервер слушает сообщения примерно так:

```
    public void Listen(string PipeName)
    {

        // Set to class level var so we can re-use in the async callback method
        _pipeName = PipeName;
        // Create the new async pipe 
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Wait for a connection
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
    }
```

Comment: Возникла следующая идея:
Сервер при запуске генерирует случайное имя для pipe и сохраняет его в пользовательском хранилище, например в реестре в ветке CurrentUser 
Клиентская часть читает имя и исползует его для отправки сообщений.

Comment: *Сервер при запуске генерирует случайное имя для pipe* Разумнее использовать некий статический префикс плюс его собственный PID.

Comment: У меня про пользователя может существовать только один сервер. Есть соответсвующие проверки через Mutex. Т.е. я не вижу разницы, случайное ли это имя или статический префикс пользователя. И какой этот префикс должен быть?

Comment: *какой этот префикс должен быть?* Идентифицирующий приложение. Чтобы ни с кем не перепутать... `'MySuperPuperServer'` - подойдёт. Будешь смотреть все пайпы - сразу поймёшь, откуда этот взялся. Опять же клиенту  будет проще найти нужный пайп или проверить себя, что не ошибся в выборе (а заодно можно по PID сверить учётки - свою и сервера,- от имени коих запущен процесс, чтобы убедиться, что это "свой" сервер). А так да - префикс нафиг не нужен.